# Cannot forward after response has been committed

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc

I am trying to forward from Servlet to JSP along setting attribute but I am getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has
>   been committed

Please help.

My code:

```
public class setPassword extends HttpServlet {

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Connection co;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gift", "root", "");
        Statement st = co.createStatement();
        System.out.println("setpassword...........");

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from generaldata");

        System.out.println("setpassword...........111");
        String userid = request.getParameter("username");

        while (rs.next()) {
            String us = rs.getString(2);
            String ps = rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println("setpassword...........222");

            System.out.println(us);
            System.out.println(userid);

            if (userid.equals(us)) {

                System.out.println(ps);
                System.out.println("setpassword...........333");

                if (ps.equals("")) {
                    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
                    String pass1 = request.getParameter("password1");
                    System.out.println("setpassword...........444");

                    if (pass.equals(pass1)) {
                        rs.updateNString(3, pass);
                        RequestDispatcher rdpassword = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
                        rdpassword.forward(request, response);
                        System.out.println("setpassword...........555");
                    } else {
                        request.setAttribute("errorPassword", "Your Password does not match...!!!");
                        RequestDispatcher rdlogin = request.getRequestDispatcher("newuser.jsp");
                        rdlogin.forward(request, response);
                        System.out.println("setpassword...........666");
                    }
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("err", "Please note you are not a New User...!!!");
                    System.out.println("setpassword.................777");
                    RequestDispatcher rdNotNew = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                    rdNotNew.forward(request, response);

                }
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("err", "Not a valid User...!!!");
                System.out.println("setpassword.................788");
                RequestDispatcher rdNotValid = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                rdNotValid.forward(request, response);
            }
            System.out.println("setpassword.................888");
        }
        System.out.println("setpassword.................999");

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        co.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste your output

Comment: If the request is forwarded once **before** the loop terminates then, the loop will continue even after the request is forwarded that will attempt to forward the request once again from another (or possibly the same depending upon the evaluation of one of the conditions) block of `if-else` causing the clumsy `java.lang.IllegalStateException` to be thrown (it may seems unusual). You may want to use a `break` statement appropriately or a flag variable in the `if-else-if` ladder to indicate the status of authentication and forward the request outside the loop using that variable.

Comment: If you're checking for user authentication then, you may just use a single query with a prepare statement like `select * from user_table where user_email=? and user_password=?` and then `if(rs.next()){//User credentials are correct. So redirect to the home page}else{//Show a message indicating bad credentials}`. There is no need to dance with a loop :)

Comment: thank you for 'prepare statement' idea............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should put a `return` immediately after the forward.
2. You should put your `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` and `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();` only inside a branch where you are not forwarding.
3. You need to figure out a way to close the db connection before the forward.

Comment: only adding return does not work, but i removed 'response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");' and added return; it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

working code.... i have specified the area where i made changes in above code

public class setPassword extends HttpServlet {

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
   **// response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");**
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    Connection co;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gift", "root", "");
        Statement st = co.createStatement();
        System.out.println("setpassword...........");

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from generaldata");

        System.out.println("setpassword...........111");
        String userid = request.getParameter("username");
        **int count = 0;**

        while (rs.next()) {
            String us = rs.getString(2);
            String ps = rs.getString(3);
            System.out.println("setpassword...........222");

            System.out.println(us);
            System.out.println(userid);

            if (userid.equals(us)) {

                **count++;**

                System.out.println(ps);
                System.out.println("setpassword...........333");

                if (ps.equals("")) {
                    String pass = request.getParameter("password");
                    String pass1 = request.getParameter("password1");
                    System.out.println("setpassword...........444");

                    if (pass.equals(pass1)) {
                        rs.updateNString(3, pass);
                        RequestDispatcher rdpassword = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
                        rdpassword.forward(request, response);
                        System.out.println("setpassword...........555");
                    } else {
                        request.setAttribute("errorPassword", "Your Password does not match...!!!");
                        RequestDispatcher rdlogin = request.getRequestDispatcher("newuser.jsp");
                        rdlogin.forward(request, response);
                        System.out.println("setpassword...........666");
                        **return;**
                    }
                } else {
                    request.setAttribute("error", "Please note you are not a New User...!!!");
                    System.out.println("setpassword.................777");
                    RequestDispatcher rdNotNew = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                    rdNotNew.forward(request, response);
                    **return;**

                }
            }
            **else{
                continue;
            }**
            System.out.println("setpassword.................888");
        }

         **if(count == 0) {
                request.setAttribute("error", "Not a valid User...!!!");
                System.out.println("setpassword.................788");
                RequestDispatcher rdNotValid = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
                rdNotValid.forward(request, response);
                return;
            }**

        System.out.println("setpassword.................999");

        rs.close();
        st.close();
        co.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
}
```